# Trouble converting txt with line breaks to JSON for querying an API

Tags: python, json

I am trying my hand at using a python script to download definitions from forvo.com

I put a list of words in a .txt document
Then, the script uses my purchased API key to access Forvo to pull mp3 files related to each word in the txt document

The script works fine when the txt document contains a single item

It gives the following error when the document contains >1 items (due to line breaks causing malformed JSON)

```
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ForvoDownloader\test.py", line 105, in <module>
    Main('es',1)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ForvoDownloader\test.py", line 75, in Main
    r = ForvoRequest(i,lang,APIKEY)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ForvoDownloader\test.py", line 39, in ForvoRequest
    data = r.json()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ForvoDownloader\requests\models.py", line 805, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

And here is the code for the script. Sorry for the length. I am new to this and don't know what you all need to see to help. So, I erred on the side of caution.

```
import forvo
import os
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

import requests
import urllib

def ForvoRequest(QUERY, LANG, apikey, ACT='word-pronunciations', FORMAT='mp3', free= True):
      # action, default is 'word-pronunciations', query, language, apikey, TRUE if free api(default), FALSE if commercial
      # Return a list of link to mp3 pronunciations for the word QUERY in LANG language.
      # FORMAT='ogg' will return a list of link to ogg pronunciations 

      if free:#default
            base_url = 'http://apifree.forvo.com/'
      else:
            #TODO: add non free base url
            base_url = 'htttp://api.forvo.com/' #is it correct?

      query_u8 = QUERY
      query_u8.decode('utf-8')

      key = [
            ('action',ACT),
            ('format','json'),
            ('word',urllib.quote(QUERY)),
            ('language',LANG),
            ('key',apikey)
            ]

      url = base_url + '/'.join(['%s/%s' % a for a in key if a[1]]) + '/'

      try:
            r = requests.get(url)
      except:
            raise
            return None

      data = r.json()

      if data[u'items']:
            #we retrieved a non empty JSON.
            #the JSON is structured like this:
            #a dictionary with 2 items, their keys are:
            #-u'attributes' (linked to info about the request we made)
            #-u'items'      (linked to a list of dictionaries)
            #in the list there is a dictionary for every pronunciation, we will search for the "mp3path" key

            paths = []
            for i in data[u'items']:
                  audioFormat = u'path'+FORMAT
                  paths.append(i[audioFormat])
            return paths

      else:
            #The json hasn't a u'items' key
            return None



def Main(lang,limit):
      #APIKEY is stored separately in another file called apikey
      with open('apikey.txt') as a:
        APIKEY=a.read()

      myfile = fileChoose()

      with open(myfile) as words:
            #We will create a directory to store downloaded mp3, it will be named /home/user/forvo/...
            home        = os.path.expanduser('~/forvo')
            lang_dir    = os.path.join(home,lang)

            for i in words:

                  r = ForvoRequest(i,lang,APIKEY)

                  if r:
                        DownloadMp3(r, limit, i, lang_dir)
                  else:                        
                        file_name = os.path.join(lang_dir,'word_not_found.txt')
                        with open(file_name,'a') as out:
                              out.write(i)

def fileChoose():
      #show a file choose dialog box
      Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
      filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
      return filename

def DownloadMp3(urlList, limit, word, folder):
      #download a mp3 file, rename it and write it in a costum folder
      for i in range(0,limit):
            mp3 = requests.get(urlList[i])                 
            file_name   = word.replace('\n','')+'.{0}'.format(i)+'.mp3'
            file_path   = os.path.join(folder, file_name)

            if not os.path.exists(folder):
                  os.makedirs(folder)              
            else:
                  with open(file_path,"wb") as out:
                        #we open a new mp3 file and we name it after the word we're downloading.
                        #The file it's opened in write-binary mode
                        out.write(mp3.content)

Main('es',2)
```

It seems I need to find a way to pass the txt file to JSON in a well-formed manner. I tried searching for examples on Stackoverflow, but I had trouble finding anything that addressed all the issues here.

Printing of r.text when text document cotains >1 item:
(I think what is happening is the script is searching the API incorrectly. Rather than cycling through each element in the txt document, it is searching for all at once. Here is the section of code that makes me think this:

```
with open(myfile) as words:
            #We will create a directory to store downloaded mp3, it will be named /home/user/forvo/...
            home        = os.path.expanduser('~/forvo')
            lang_dir    = os.path.join(home,lang)

            for i in words:

                  r = ForvoRequest(i,lang,APIKEY)

                  if r:
                        DownloadMp3(r, limit, i, lang_dir)
```

And the readout....

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <base href="http://forvo.com/" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Forvo - Page not found</title>
        <meta name="description" content="The largest pronunciation dictionary in the world. All the words in all the languages pronounced by native speakers" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="language" content="en" />
        <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="49A70CD965F0664320B55CB0E75C86EB" />
        <meta name="baidu-site-verification" content="6R8984qqM6" />
        <meta name="author" content="Forvo Team" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="//static00.forvo.com/_presentation/img/forvo_og.png" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="Forvo - Page not found" />
        <meta property="fb:admins" content="725168915" />
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="186058231446689" />
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="app" />
        <meta name="twitter:description" content="Forvo pronunciation official app. Learn everywhere." />
        <meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="375819093" />
        <meta name="twitter:app:id:ipad" content="375819093" />
        <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=375819093, affiliate-data=at=11lrGv"/>




        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="forvo.com/apple-touch-icon.png">



        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//static00.forvo.com/_presentation/assets/css/vendor/normalize.css?v=54">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="//static00.forvo.com/_presentation/assets/css/main-ltr.css?v=54">

        <link rel="start" type="text/html" href="http://forvo.com/" title="Home" />


        <script src="//static00.forvo.com/_presentation/assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
        <script type='text/javascript'>

            var googletag = googletag || {};
            googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
            (function() {
                var gads = document.createElement('script');
                gads.async = true;
                gads.type = 'text/javascript';
                var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
                gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                    '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
                var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
            })();

        </script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>

            googletag.cmd.push(function() {

                var map_preheader = googletag.sizeMapping().
                addSize([0, 0], []).
                addSize([1000, 300], [[980, 90], [980, 250], [970, 250], [970, 90]]).
                build();

                var map_leaderboard = googletag.sizeMapping().
                addSize([0, 0], []).
                addSize([320, 100], [[320, 100], [320, 50]]).
                addSize([720, 100], [468, 60]).
                addSize([800, 100], [728, 90]).
                addSize([1000, 100], [[728, 90], [970, 90]]).
                build();

                var map_content = googletag.sizeMapping().
                addSize([0, 0], []).
                addSize([320, 300], [300, 250]).
                addSize([500, 100], [468, 60]).
                addSize([800, 100], [728, 90]).
                build();

                var map_sidebar = googletag.sizeMapping().
                addSize([0, 0], []).
                addSize([320, 300], [300, 250]).
                addSize([640, 1], []).
                addSize([960, 100], [[300, 250], [300, 600]]).
                build();

                var map_footer = googletag.sizeMapping().
                addSize([0, 0], []).
                addSize([800, 100], [728, 90]).
                addSize([1000, 100], [[728, 90], [970, 90]]).
                build();

                googletag.defineSlot('/7394592/FV_LEADERBOARD', [[320, 100], [320, 50], [468, 60], [728, 90], [970, 90]], 'div-gpt-ad-1435318051797-3').defineSizeMapping(map_leaderboard).addService(googletag.pubads());
                googletag.defineSlot('/7394592/FV_CONTENT_1', [[300, 250], [468, 60], [728, 90]], 'div-gpt-ad-1435318051797-0').defineSizeMapping(map_content).addService(googletag.pubads());
                googletag.defineSlot('/7394592/FV_CONTENT_2', [[300, 250], [468, 60], [728, 90]], 'div-gpt-ad-1435318051797-1').defineSizeMapping(map_content).addService(googletag.pubads());
                googletag.defineSlot('/7394592/FV_SIDEBAR_1', [[300, 250], [300, 600]], 'div-gpt-ad-1435318051797-5').defineSizeMapping(map_sidebar).addService(googletag.pubads());
                googletag.defineSlot('/7394592/FV_SIDEBAR_2', [[300, 250], [300, 600]], 'div-gpt-ad-1435318051797-6').defineSizeMapping(map_sidebar).addService(googletag.pubads());
                googletag.defineSlot('/7394592/FV_FOOTER', [[728, 90], [970, 90]], 'div-gpt-ad-1435318051797-2').defineSizeMapping(map_footer).addService(googletag.pubads());



                googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
                googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs(true,true);
                googletag.enableServices();
            });

        </script>

        <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

                <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[

          (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
          (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
          m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
          })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

          ga('create', 'UA-11977263-2', 'forvo.com');
          ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
          ga('send', 'pageview');

        //]]>
        </script>


    </head>
    <body class="ltr" >


        <div id="wrap">

            <div id="player" class="hidden"></div>


            <!--[if lt IE 8]>
                <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
            <![endif]-->

            <header id="header">

                <p id="logo"><a href="http://forvo.com/"><img src="//static00.forvo.com/_presentation/assets/img/layout/logo.png" alt="Forvo homepage" /></a></p>

                <nav id="nav_user" >
                                        <ul>
                                                    <li class="login"><a href="http://forvo.com/login/" rel="nofollow" title="Log in">Log in</a></li>
                            <li class="signup"><a href="http://forvo.com/signup/" rel="nofollow" title="Sign up">Sign up</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                </nav>

                <nav id="nav_common">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="add"><a href="http://forvo.com/word-add/">Add words</a></li>
                        <li class="pronounce"><a href="http://forvo.com/pronounce/">Pronounce</a></li>
                                                <li class="listen"><a href="http://forvo.com/listen-learn/">Listen &amp; Learn</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </header>

            <div id="wrap_main_nav_and_search">
                <span class="trigger_menu">&nbsp;</span>

                <nav id="nav_main">
                    <ul>
                                                <li class="languages "><a href="http://forvo.com/languages/">Languages</a></li>
                                                <li class="categories "><a href="http://forvo.com/tags/" rel="nofollow">Categories</a></li>
                        <li class="pronunciations "><a href="http://forvo.com/pronounce/">Pronounce</a></li>
                        <li class="users "><a href="http://forvo.com/users/">Users</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

                                <section class="main_search" id="main_search">
                    <div class="content">

                        <form method="post" action="/search/" id="search" class="classic"> <!-- "classic" (default) or "new" -->
                            <nav>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="classic"><a id="search_word" href="#search_word_holder" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'search', 'searchword')">Pronounce</a></li>
                                    <li class="new"><a id="search_language" href="#search_language_holder" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'search', 'searchtranslate')">Translate + Pronounce BETA</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>


                            <div class="search_word_holder" id="search_word_holder">
                                <label for="word_search_header">Search for a word</label>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Search for a word" name="word_search" id="word_search_header" value="" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="search_language_holder" id="search_language_holder">
                                <label for="language_search_header">Idiomas</label>
                                <select name="language_search_header" id="language_search_header" disabled="disabled">
                                                                                                                                                            <optgroup label="English">
                                                                                                                                            <option value="en-ar" >English - Arabic</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="en-fr" >English - French</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="en-de" >English - German</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="en-it" >English - Italian</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="en-ja" >English - Japanese</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="en-ru" >English - Russian</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="en-es" >English - Spanish</option>
                                                                                    </optgroup>
                                                                                                                                                            <optgroup label="French">
                                                                                                                                            <option value="fr-ar" >French - Arabic</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="fr-en" >French - English</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="fr-de" >French - German</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="fr-it" >French - Italian</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="fr-ja" >French - Japanese</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="fr-ru" >French - Russian</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="fr-es" >French - Spanish</option>
                                                                                    </optgroup>
                                                                                                                                                            <optgroup label="Spanish">
                                                                                                                                            <option value="es-ar" >Spanish - Arabic</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="es-en" >Spanish - English</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="es-fr" >Spanish - French</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="es-de" >Spanish - German</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="es-it" >Spanish - Italian</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="es-ja" >Spanish - Japanese</option>
                                                                                                                                            <option value="es-ru" >Spanish - Russian</option>
                                                                                    </optgroup>
                                                                    </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="actions">
                                <button type="submit">Buscar</button>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </section>
                            </div>

            <!-- /7394592/FV_LEADERBOARD -->
            <div id='div-gpt-ad-1435318051797-3' class="ad ad-fv-leaderboard">
            <script type='text/javascript'>

            googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1435318051797-3'); });

            </script>
            </div>

            <div id="displayer"><div class="mainpage fullpage page_error404">

    <section class="main_section">
        <header>
            <div class="title_holder">
                <h1>404 - Page not found</h1>
            </div>
            <p class="info">The page you are looking doesn't exist.</p>
        </header>

        <article>
            <h1>Go to <a href="/">Forvo Homepage</a></h1>
            <p>If you think it should be something here please <a href="/contact/">contact us</a></p>
        </article>


    </section>


</div>



<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-11977263-8', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

</div> <!-- /#displayer -->

            <!-- /7394592/FV_FOOTER -->
            <div id='div-gpt-ad-1435318051797-2' class="ad ad-fv-footer">
            <script type='text/javascript'>

            googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1435318051797-2'); });

            </script>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- #wrap -->

        <footer id="footer">

            <div class="content">

                                <section id="footer_interfaz_langs">
                    <em>Choose your language:</em>
                    <ul id="footer_main_languages_list">
                                                                            <li><a href="http://de.forvo.com/404" hreflang="de">Deutsch</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li>English</li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://es.forvo.com/404" hreflang="es">Español</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://fr.forvo.com/404" hreflang="fr">Français</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://it.forvo.com/404" hreflang="it">Italiano</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://ja.forvo.com/404" hreflang="ja">日本語</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://nl.forvo.com/404" hreflang="nl">Nederlands</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://pl.forvo.com/404" hreflang="pl">Polski</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://pt.forvo.com/404" hreflang="pt">Português</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://ru.forvo.com/404" hreflang="ru">Русский</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://tr.forvo.com/404" hreflang="tr">Türkçe</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://zh.forvo.com/404" hreflang="zh">汉语</a></li>
                                                                    </ul>
                                        <p id="interfaz_other_languages_trigger"><a href="#footer_other_languages_list">and even more languages</a></p>
                    <ul id="footer_other_languages_list">

                                                                            <li><a href="http://ar.forvo.com/404" hreflang="ar">العربية</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://bg.forvo.com/404" hreflang="bg">Български</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://bs.forvo.com/404" hreflang="bs">Bosanski</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://ca.forvo.com/404" hreflang="ca">Català</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://cs.forvo.com/404" hreflang="cs">Čeština</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://da.forvo.com/404" hreflang="da">Dansk</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://el.forvo.com/404" hreflang="el">Ελληνικά</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://eu.forvo.com/404" hreflang="eu">Euskara</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://fa.forvo.com/404" hreflang="fa">پارسی</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://fi.forvo.com/404" hreflang="fi">Suomi</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://hak.forvo.com/404" hreflang="hak">客家语</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://he.forvo.com/404" hreflang="he">עברית</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://hi.forvo.com/404" hreflang="hi">हिन्दी</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://hr.forvo.com/404" hreflang="hr">Hrvatski</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://hu.forvo.com/404" hreflang="hu">Magyar</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://hy.forvo.com/404" hreflang="hy">Հայերեն</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://ind.forvo.com/404" hreflang="ind">Bahasa Indonesia</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://ko.forvo.com/404" hreflang="ko">한국어</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://lv.forvo.com/404" hreflang="lv">Latviešu</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://no.forvo.com/404" hreflang="no">Norsk bokmål</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://pa.forvo.com/404" hreflang="pa">ਪੰਜਾਬੀ</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://ro.forvo.com/404" hreflang="ro">Română</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://sk.forvo.com/404" hreflang="sk">Slovenčina</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://sr.forvo.com/404" hreflang="sr">Српски / Srpski</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://sv.forvo.com/404" hreflang="sv">Svenska</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://th.forvo.com/404" hreflang="th">ไทย</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://tt.forvo.com/404" hreflang="tt">Tatarça</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://uk.forvo.com/404" hreflang="uk">Українська</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://vi.forvo.com/404" hreflang="vi">Tiếng Việt</a></li>
                                                                                                    <li><a href="http://yue.forvo.com/404" hreflang="yue">粵文</a></li>
                                                                    </ul>
                                    </section>

                <section id="footer_nav">
                    <em>Forvo, the pronunciation dictionary</em>
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://pronuncionary.com/">Blog</a>
                            <li><a href="http://iphone.forvo.com/">iPhone</a>
                            <li><a href="http://forvo.com/tools/">Tools</a>
                            <li><a href="http://api.forvo.com/">API</a>
                            <li><a href="http://forvo.com/license/" rel="nofollow">License</a>
                            <li><a href="http://forvo.com/privacy/" rel="nofollow">Privacy</a>
                            <li><a href="http://forvo.com/about/">About Forvo</a>
                            <li><a href="http://forvo.com/contact/" rel="nofollow">Contact us</a>
                            <li><a href="http://forvo.com/faq/"><abbr title="Frequently Asked Questions">FAQ</abbr></a>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>

                    <div id="footer_donate">
                        <form target="_top" method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"><input type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" name="cmd"><input type="hidden" value="GFDPL77XZW3L2" name="hosted_button_id"><input type="image" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'footer', 'donate')" alt="Donate to Forvo" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_SM.gif"><img width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_ES/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt=""></form>                    
                    </div>

                </section>


            </div>
        </footer>



        <script type="text/javascript">
        var FRONTEND_PRESENTATION_DIR='/_presentation';
        var _SERVER_HOST='forvo.com';
        var _AUDIO_HTTP_HOST='audio.forvo.com:80';
        var player_path='/_presentation/swf/play.swf';
        </script>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//static00.forvo.com/_presentation/assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="//static00.forvo.com/_presentation/assets/js/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js?v=54"></script>
        <script src="//static00.forvo.com/_presentation/assets/js/vendor/jquery.magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

        <script src="//static00.forvo.com/_presentation/assets/js/plugins.min.js?v=54"></script>
        <script src="//static00.forvo.com/_presentation/assets/js/main.min.js?v=54"></script>




    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the malformed JSON that your script is choking on?

Comment: Could you help me with extracting this? I'm assuming I need to enter some code to pull the JSON to a separate file.

Comment: Since you're using `requests`, you should be able to get the raw response from [`r.text`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.text) (rather than `r.json()`). If the response JSON is truly malformed, you'll have to do some manual repair on it yourself before any tools can interpret it.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, and I fear that I may be in over my head. I tried changing ('format','json'), to ('format','text'), and data = r.json() to data = r.text. Getting a different error, likely because the change I made in no way relates to your suggestion. I hope I haven't wasted your time.

Comment: Leave `('format', 'json')` alone, as you want to get the response formatted the same as before to see why it isn't parsing correctly.

Comment: `print` or log the resulting r.text and edit it into the question.

Comment: Thank you again. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

From your response text, note:

```
<title>Forvo - Page not found</title>
```

The script is failing because the site is not returning JSON, it's returning an error; it doesn't know what you're asking. You'll need to check the API and find out if you're able to do what you're trying to do.

**Update based on edit:**

You're doing:

```
with open(myfile) as words:
    for i in words:
        # do something with i
```

When you iterate over a file, it will read one line at a time. I'm guessing that your file may be space delimited (all words on one line separated by spaces), in which case you'll need to split `words` on spaces:

```
with open(myfile) as words:
    for i in words.read().split():
        # do something with i
```

Comment: This must have something to do with the way the script is pulling from the text document. When my text document contains only one word to search, I get a different response text and the script works.